# error creating custom aggregate function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Trying to create a custom aggregate function in oracle that returns the first non-null value, or a default value.

I build the type with

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE aggnvlimp AS OBJECT
(
    val           VARCHAR2(32767),
    default_value VARCHAR2(32767),

    STATIC
    FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize(
        sctx IN OUT aggnvlimp
    )
        RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate(
        self IN OUT aggnvlimp,
        VALUE IN VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate(
        self IN aggnvlimp,
        returnvalue OUT VARCHAR2,
        flags IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge(
        self IN OUT aggnvlimp,
        ctx2 IN aggnvlimp
    ) RETURN NUMBER
);
```

the implementation

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY aggnvlimp IS
    STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize(
        sctx IN OUT aggnvlimp
    )
        RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        sctx := aggnvlimp(null, 'N/D');
        RETURN odciconst.success;
    END;

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate(
        self IN OUT aggnvlimp,
        VALUE IN VARCHAR2
    )
        RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        self.val := nvl(self.val, value);

        RETURN odciconst.success;
    END;

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate(
        self IN aggnvlimp,
        returnvalue OUT varchar2,
        flags IN NUMBER
    )
        RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        returnvalue := nvl(self.val, self.default_value);
        RETURN odciconst.success;
    END;

    MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge(
        self IN OUT aggnvlimp,
        ctx2 IN aggnvlimp
    )
        RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        self.val := nvl(self.val, ctx2.val);
        RETURN odciconst.success;
    END;
END;
```

and they both seem to succeed. When building the function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aggnvl(input VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
    PARALLEL_ENABLE
    AGGREGATE USING aggnvlimp;
```

I get

```
[2021-03-06 09:22:59] 3:29:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
[2021-03-06 09:22:59] . @ ;
[2021-03-06 09:22:59] The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

I have followed the example in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm#CECJAAJG

Any ideas?

Comment: It just compiles fine for me in [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com)

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar, you're right. it works there. It fails on my instance, of "Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0". No idea why.

Comment: Is this an exercise? Because object oriented pl/sql in Oracle are rather exotic. And you may check function COALESCE which should do the same .

Comment: I don't think PARALLEL_ENABLE has any impact - what do you think can be parallized here? But RESULT_CACHE may improve the performance.

Comment: Compiles for me in 19.3.0.0.0. (By the way, it's probably not important but since 18c there is both a `version_full` and a `version_legacy` in `v$instance`. SQL\*Plus 18c onwards displays both but I'm not sure if older clients do. It's therefore possibly that you are actually on a later version than 19.0.0.0.0.)

Comment: What tool are you using? Does it work in SQL\*Plus?

Comment: You would get that error, for example, if the semicolon after the `END` command was missing, something like `... (code)  ... return (something); end` and then a slash on a line by itself. Note the `end` command is not ended in a semicolon. Check your code for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to create a custom aggregate function in oracle that returns the first non-null value, or a default value.

If this is not an exercise, then this is much more simply done using existing functions.  You need to define three things:

- `<col>` is the column you want the first value of.
- `<ordering col>` is the definition of "first".
- `<default value>` is the default value.

Then you can use `keep` to implement "first" and `coalesce()` to substitute the default value?

```
coalesce( max(<col>) keep (dense_rank first
                           order by (case when col is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                                    <ordering col>
                          ),
          <default value>
        )
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your comment. This is not an exercise. I am trying to see if custom aggregate functions work inside `PIVOT` queries, but I was unable even to create the aggregate function on my system.

Comment: @user103716 . . . They should . . . but I don't recommend using `pivot` anyway.  Just use conditional aggregation.